# Get Count in Group By query with Room Database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have model class named Medicine which is below

```
@Entity(tableName = "medicine")
data class Medicine(

    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    var id: Long,

    @SerializedName("productName")
    var product_name: String,

    @SerializedName("companyName")
    var company_name: String

   )
}
```

Now in DAO class I want to do query like below

```
  @Query("SELECT *, COUNT(product_name) as Total FROM medicine GROUP BY product_name")
    fun getAllMedicineGroupByProductName(): LiveData<List<Medicine>>
```

Now my question is, how to get **Total**?

I would not like to modify Model so if it is better solution without adding field like **Total** to Model class then it would be fine

I am using data-binding so, how to fetch Total over there like

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvProductName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{`Product Name : `+medicine.product_name}"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Here i can get product_name easily but do not know how to get **Total**? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: *Here i can get product_name easily but do not know how to get **Total**?*, as you are getting count then it will be treated as **Total** or correct me?

Comment: Sorry I can not get you, like in Medicine class I have product_name that's why I can easily get product_name but how to get Total?

Comment: You must be getting count with the above query then that will be treated as **Total**, then what you needed more or explain bit about your query?

Comment: Yes but in xml file I am not getting  android:text="@{`Product Name : `+medicine.total}"

Comment: `viewModel observe` did you check what you are getting? Does it return anything?

Comment: no, let me check over there

Comment: in Observer also I am getting Medicine data nothing more than that

Answer (score 1):

You only getting a Medicine object, it has no Total. You need to get object (POJO) that has @Embedded Medicine object and Total

like

```
data class MedicineWithTotal(
    @Embedded val medicine: Medicine,
    val Total: Int
)
```

used like :-

```
    database.medicineDao().insertMedicine(Medicine(0,"tableta","ZZZ"))
    database.medicineDao().insertMedicine(Medicine(0,"tabletb","ZZZ"))
    database.medicineDao().insertMedicine(Medicine(0,"tabletc","ZZZ"))
    database.medicineDao().insertMedicine(Medicine(0,"tabletc","XXX"))
    database.medicineDao().insertMedicine(Medicine(0,"tabletc","YYY"))
    val medicinewithcount = database.medicineDao().getAllMedicineGroupByProductName()
    for (mwt: MedicineWithTotal in medicinewithcount) {
        Log.d("COUNT","Product = " + mwt.medicine.product_name + " Count = " + mwt.Total)
    }
    for (mwt: MedicineWithTotal in medicinewithcount) {
        Log.d("MEDICINEWITHCOUNT","Product = " + mwt.medicine.product_name + " Count = " + mwt.Total)
    }
```

does

> D/COUNT: Product = tableta Count = 1
>
> D/COUNT: Product = tabletb Count = 1
>
> D/COUNT: Product = tabletc Count = 3

*(not done with LiveData as easy not to)*